# Not getting padlock though I installed ssl

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

I have recently installed ssl certificate through CloudFlare. I'm getting https but not getting padlock. I tried using really simple ssl WordPress plugin but I could not help mixed content.

My website URL: https://claimstock.com

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the developer console of Chrome clearly shows the problems:

```
Mixed Content: ... requested an insecure image 'http://35.232.70.59/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/construction-image38-2-free-img.jpg'
```

This means that your site includes resources loaded with plain `http://` even though the site is served with `https://`.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID ... 35.232.70.59/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/911-2.jpg:1
```

This mean your site tries to download resources via `https://` from 35.232.70.59. But the certificate for 35.232.70.59 is a self-signed certificate for `www.example.com`. A self-signed certificate can not be trusted and apart from that the name of the certificate does not match the name in the URL.

Comment: so what exactly is the solution for that

Comment: @Ashwin: find out where these includes come from, what's their purpose is and either delete or fix these. You should know your site better than somebody else here. If you don't find it try to remove any wordpress plugins you have until the problem is fixed because maybe the problem is caused by some plugin.